# POST request treated as a GET request

Tags: java, http

Why does the following code print "Method: GET" instead of the "Method: POST"?

I need it to authorize on http://www.havenandhearth.com/portal/ programmatically.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.havenandhearth.com/portal/sec/login");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            String parameters = "username=xxx&password=yyy";

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(parameters.length()));

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(parameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responsecode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responsecode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("Unable to make POST request. Response code: " + responsecode);
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Method: " + conn.getRequestMethod());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If I change URL to http://httpbin.org/post it works as expected.

To make it happen you need to replace xxx and yyy with the actual account credentials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i run your code i see this result: `Method: POST`

Comment: @David Herrero Ah, that's because of the invalid account credentials, sorry

Comment: Ok, i think that when you make a succesfull POST with your credentials, the web page redirects you to the home page, so the conn now makes a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was due to automatic redirect.

If I set

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Yep, you are right, you answered your own question! haha, congrats
PD: i never heard about that game...seems interesting

Comment: @David Herrero Yep, you should definitely look at it